# The best way to generalise a code for toggling the disabled attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code (*) for toggling the disabled attribute beetween two buttons works and you can check it at http://jsfiddle.net/cNSVX/3/.

I was wondering what is the best way to generalise this code in order to attach this behaviour to a couple of buttons.
Something like the following.

```
body.onload(togglingButton(elem1, elem2));
```

---

```
$('#filterOpened').click(function() {
    $('#filterOpened').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#filterClosed').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#filterClosed').click(function() {
    $('#filterClosed').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#filterOpened').removeAttr('disabled');
});

function togglingButton (elem1, elem2) {
    if (elem2.attr('disabled')) {
        elem1.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        elem2.removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
        elem2.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        elem1.removeAttr('disabled');
   } 
};
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below with jQuery.  Also if you are using jQuery 1.6+ then you should be using `.prop()` to toggle your `disabled` property.

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value.

```
​$('button').click(function(){ //<---  attaches click to all button's
      $(this).prop('disabled',true);  //<-- only disable the clicked button
      $('button').not(this).prop('disabled',false);  //<-- all button's but the clicked one should be enabled
});​​​
```

here's an example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cNSVX/5/

If you are planning on excluding some buttons out of the toggling it would be a good idea to give them a class so you can select the ones you need/don't need easier

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this would be to use jQuery's `.data()` function to link the two elements, then assign a single event handler to both:

```
function disableToggle(el1,el2) {
    el1.data('partner',el2);
    el2.data('partner',el1);

    el1.add(el2).on('click',function(){
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        $(this).data('partner').prop('disabled',false);
    });
}

$(function(){
    var opened = $('#filterOpened');
    var closed = $('#filterClosed');

    disableToggle(opened,closed)
});
```

I've created a demo:

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/YJ6rp/)